# Errors for using a class template in another class

Tags: c++, class

I have a class template `Foo` which has a private data member whose data type is `std::vector<T>` and a public constructor whose argument is used to resize the vector.

```
template<typename T>
class Foo
{
  private:
  std::vector<T> Vector_;
  
  Foo(){}
  
  public:
  Foo( const int& size )
  {
    Vector_.resize(size);
  }
};
```

On the other hand, I have another class `Bar` which has a private data member of `Foo<int>`.

```
class Bar
{
  private:
  Foo<int> AFoo(3);
  
  public:
  Bar(){}
};
```

Finally, I would like to declare a `Bar` in the main function.

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  Bar ABar;
  
  return 0;
}
```

But I got the following error: *expected identifier before numeric constant* indicated at the character `3` of `Foo<int> AFoo(3);`.

I am appreciate if anyone knows how to fix this error.

Comment: Try `Foo<int> AFoo{3};`

Comment: It's probably trying to parse that statement as a function declaration, considering that it's expecting an identifier.